# Python - Selenium cannot click href="javascript:void(0);"

Tags: python, selenium

Whenever I try to scrape Eastleigh website it does everything it needs to do. it goes to the URL, auto clicks "Advanced Settings" Writes in the decision date clicks search and gets all the href links but when it TRIES to go to them it fails... Why? All it needs to do is click the href links but it won't ;-;

Can someone help fix this please?

Code:

```
import sys
import time
import config
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver

print("1. Custom Date")
print("2. Last Week")
choice = input("#: ")
if choice == "1":
    print("Start Example: 1/8/2018")
    startDate = input("Start Date: ")
    print("Stop Example: 30/8/2018")
    stopDate = input("Stop Date: ")

elif choice == "2":
    sd = str(datetime.datetime.today().day) # Gets day of the month
    sm = str(datetime.datetime.today().month) # Gets month of the year
    sy = str(datetime.datetime.today().year) # Gets year
    nsd = int(sd) # Turns string variable "sd" into an integer
    startDate = "%s/%s/%s" % (nsd-7, sm, sy) # Makes a new date string. Minus 7 off of the original date to go back 1 week
    stopDate = "%s/%s/%s" % (nsd-1, sm, sy) # Makes a new date string. Minus 1 off of the original date, (Minusing 1 was Steve's idea, not mine.)
else:
    print("This is not a choice.")
    print("Press Enter to exit...")
    input("")
    sys.exit()

url = "https://planning.eastleigh.gov.uk/s/public-register"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Goten\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//li[@class='slds-tabs_default__item'])[1]").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("728:0").click() # This changes for some reason... I cannot quite find a way to make it stay the same...
driver.find_element_by_id("728:0").send_keys(startDate)

driver.find_element_by_id("744:0").click() # This also changes
driver.find_element_by_id("744:0").send_keys(stopDate)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@name='submit'])[2]").click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='View More']").click()

result = []

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".slds-truncate a")
links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in elements]

result.extend(links)

print(result)

for link in result:
    result.remove(link)
    driver.get(link)
    for i in range(1):
        div = driver.find_element_by_id("slds-form-element__group").text
        log = open("log.txt", "a")
        log.write(div + "\n")
    log.write("\n")

#driver.close()
```

Output:

```
[8520:11412:0926/001704.487:ERROR:install_util.cc(603)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59340/devtools/browser/bc325d32-310c-43e6-b8cf-dcfceaebf5a5
['javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);', 'javascript:void(0);']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    import urls.eastleigh
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\code\urls\eastleigh.py", line 61, in <module>
    driver.get(link)
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 332, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unsupported protocol
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Which line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you cannot count on those ids, as they are generated dynamically, as noted by yourself.
A hackie solution would be:

```
...
inputs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(" input")

received_from_index = 1
received_to_index = 2
decision_from_index = 3
decision_to_index = 4

received_from = inputs[received_from_index]
received_to = inputs[received_to_index]

received_from.clear()
received_from.send_keys(startDate)

received_to.clear()
received_to.send_keys(stopDate)
```

This will fill out the fields (not sure if you need to fill all of them).
After that, your script would submit and get the results page correctly.

You will need to revise this part of your code:

```
for link in result:
    result.remove(link)
    driver.get(link)
    ...
```

For the second part of what you need:

```
...
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='View More']").click()

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="arcusbuilt__PApplication__c"]/div/div/h4/a""")

print "Total of planning applications : ", len(links)


for link_index in range(1, len(links) +1):
    result_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="arcusbuilt__PApplication__c"]/div[%d]/div/h4/a"""%link_index)

    result_link.click()
    print "visiting link %d"%link_index

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "BackButton")))

    time.sleep(3)
    #DO WHAT YOU NEED HERE...

    back_btn = driver.find_element_by_name("BackButton")
    back_btn.click()
```

Good luck!

Comment: The issue wasn't obtaining the results page but logging the pages and clicking on them using the HREF, but this is also a really nice answer considering I have other code issues, thanks.

Comment: @FeitanPortor Now I understood the main part of your question. Check back my answer for clarification

Comment: [@id="arcusbuilt__PApplication__c"]/div/div/h4/a because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//* .
 [@id="arcusbuilt__PApplication__c"]/div/div/h4/a' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: check it back again